# how to generate a rolling mean grouped by columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate a rolling 2 average of `col3` grouped by `col2`. What I'm struggling with is populating the `NaN` values to take the previously calculated rolling mean.

DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""col1,col2,col3
0,A,1
0,A,2
0,B,3
0,B,4
1,A,5
1,A,6
1,B,7
1,B,8
2,A,9
2,A,10
2,B,11
2,B,12
3,A
3,A
3,B
3,B
4,A
4,A
4,B
4,B
"""))
```

Tried:

```py
df.groupby(["col2"])["col3"].rolling(2).mean()

col2    
A     0      NaN
      1      1.5
      4      3.5
      5      5.5
      8      7.5
      9      9.5
      12     NaN
      13     NaN
      16     NaN
      17     NaN
B     2      NaN
      3      3.5
      6      5.5
      7      7.5
      10     9.5
      11    11.5
      14     NaN
      15     NaN
      18     NaN
      19     NaN
```

What I want (looking at `A` as an example):

```
    col1 col2  col3
       0    A   1.0
       0    A   2.0
       0    B   3.0
       0    B   4.0
       1    A   5.0
       1    A   6.0
       1    B   7.0
       1    B   8.0
       2    A   9.0
       2    A  10.0
       2    B  11.0
       2    B  12.0
       3    A   NaN # (10 + 9) / 2 = 9.5
       3    A   NaN # (9.5 + 10) / 2 = 9.75
       3    B   NaN # ...
       3    B   NaN
       4    A   NaN # (9.75 + 9.5) / 2 = 9.625
       4    A   NaN # (9.625 + ...)
       4    B   NaN
       4    B   NaN
```

If we can offset the rolling mean to start at the first `NaN` that would be great.

If this can't be done using `rolling` then happy to go for a for loop solution?

Comment: Could you explain how you are in fact trying to populate your NaN values?! Is it going to be grouped by col1 or col2?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

def my_fun(d):
    return reduce(lambda x, _: x.fillna(x.rolling(2, min_periods=2).mean().shift()), range(d['col3'].isna().sum()), d)

df = df.groupby('col2').apply(my_fun)
df

    col1 col2     col3
0      0    A   1.0000
1      0    A   2.0000
2      0    B   3.0000
3      0    B   4.0000
4      1    A   5.0000
5      1    A   6.0000
6      1    B   7.0000
7      1    B   8.0000
8      2    A   9.0000
9      2    A  10.0000
10     2    B  11.0000
11     2    B  12.0000
12     3    A   9.5000
13     3    A   9.7500
14     3    B  11.5000
15     3    B  11.7500
16     4    A   9.6250
17     4    A   9.6875
18     4    B  11.6250
19     4    B  11.6875
```

Comment: Works great when grouping by 1 column, do you know why it doesn't work for grouping by multiple columns?

Comment: Hello, in this sample data if we for example group by `col1` and `col2` we will have only 2 observations per group so the solution cannot take at least 1 pair of non - NaN values to fill the NaN ones. I think that is the reason.

Comment: I've tried it against a dataset with multiple columns with available observations and this solution just keeps the `NaN`s as is...I've tried adding `groupby` inside the lambda but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Got it working for multiple columns by doing this `df.groupby(['col2', 'col5', 'col14'])[['col3']].apply(my_fun)`

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be a bit difficult to guess what was happening when sample data differs from the original data. But in general providing a sample data set that clearly resembles the original one will help to get relevant answers.